# How do I alphabetize the array by first name in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3

This is my current model class code.

```
final class ContactData
{
    static let sharedInstance = ContactData()

    private var contactList : [Contact] =
            [Contact(name:"Mike Smith",email:"mike@smith.com"),
             Contact(name:"John Doe",email:"john@doe.com"),
             Contact(name:"Jane Doe",email:"jane@doe.com")]


    private init()
    {
        // SORTING HERE
    }

    var index = 0

    func newContact(new:Contact)
    {
        contactList.append(new)
        //sort
    }

    func updateContact(updated:Contact)
    {
        contactList[index]=updated
        //sort
    }

    func  previousContact() -> Contact
    {
        index-=1
        if index < 0
        {
            index = contactList.count-1
        }
        return contactList[index]
    }

    func nextContact() -> Contact
    {
        index+=1
        if index == contactList.count
        {
            index = 0
        }
        return contactList[index]
    }

    func firstContact() -> Contact
    {
        return contactList[0]
    }

    func currentContact() -> Contact
    {
        return contactList[index]
    }
}
```

Everything is running properly but I've tried alphabetizing the array of `Contact`s using:

```
var sortedContacts = contactList.sorted{
            $0.localizedCaseinsensitiveCompare($1)==ComparisonResult.orderedAscending}
        }
```

but I am getting an error:

> Value of type '`Contact`' has no member '`localizedCaseinsensitiveCompare`'

Looking through the questions here I have only been able to find that single way to alphabetize the array.

I am running Swift 3 and Xcode 8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your class Contact conform to Comparable protocol:

```
class Contact: Comparable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let name: String
    let email: String
    init(name: String, email: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
    }
    var description: String {
        return name + " - " + email
    }
    // provide your custom comparison
    static func <(lhs: Contact, rhs: Contact) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(rhs.name)   == .orderedAscending ||
               lhs.email.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(rhs.email) == .orderedAscending
    }
    // you will need also to make it conform to Equatable
    static func ==(lhs: Contact, rhs: Contact) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.email == rhs.email
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing

```
let c1 = Contact(name:"Mike Smith",email:"mike@smith.com")
let c2 = Contact(name:"John Doe",email:"john1@doe.com")
let c3 = Contact(name:"John Doe",email:"john2@doe.com")
let c4 = Contact(name:"Jane Doe",email:"jane2@doe.com")
let c5 = Contact(name:"Jane Doe",email:"jane1@doe.com")

let people = [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5]
print(people)   // "[Mike Smith - mike@smith.com, John Doe - john1@doe.com, John Doe - john2@doe.com, Jane Doe - jane2@doe.com, Jane Doe - jane1@doe.com]\n"
print(people.sorted())  // "[Jane Doe - jane1@doe.com, Jane Doe - jane2@doe.com, John Doe - john1@doe.com, John Doe - john2@doe.com, Mike Smith - mike@smith.com]\n"
```

Comment: Some things to consider with this solution. Everything is tied to `name` only. This assumes you always want to compare by name and ignore email. It treats two different contacts with the same name but different email as being equal. That can cause lots of subtle bugs. It would probably be best if email was compared of the names are equal.

Comment: My comment is to the OP provide his custom sort

Comment: Or compare the description

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare `Contact` custom classes case insensitively. You should compare the `name` properties of them:

```
var sortedContacts = contactList.sorted { $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1.name) == .orderedAscending} }
```

Comment: Or make Contact conform to Comparable protocol

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, it's a better approach if you are planning to use sorting a lot in your code.

Comment: @the4kman By doing this in my playground it is now throwing an error where my functions are not basically nonsexist.

Comment: @LeoDabus wouldn't that mean that I have to pull the data from each instance to a placeholder then compare those two ( like a java bubble sort)